# Track activity during build/tests execution in CircleCI container

Tags: docker, circleci

I would like to track activity during build/tests execution in CircleCI container via file which is generated during the process and keeps track of build/tests activity.

For e.g.

```
CircleCI starts configurations according to yml instructions
Deploys container
Checks-out code
Starts the build/tests (X file is created which keeps track of build/tests process)
In progress… (how can I see X file content to track the progress here ?)
In progress… (how can I see X file content to track the progress here ?)
Execution completes
Store artifacts
Passed (I can see X file content at the end in Artifacts tab)
```

After the check-out of the code, I can get container IP address and also tried SSH but it doesn’t allow to ssh in it which seems obvious. For e.g.

## CircleCi container public ip address

```
CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS=$(wget -qO- http://checkip.amazonaws.com)
echo $CONTAINER_IP_ADDRESS
```

Is there any way to get the particular file contain during the execution or I need to wait till execution completes and stores artifacts? Can CircleCI add facility to see box content before storing artifact?

I've also posted this question on the CircleCI forum:

https://discuss.circleci.com/t/track-activity-during-build-tests-execution-in-circleci-container/21429

Comment: I doubt you'd be able to SSH into a running CircleCI container unless you're using the SSH feature in the build UI, and that's really only for debugging. However, you could push a file out from inside the build at any time you like, if you have a service/server to push it to.

Comment: Halfer's comment should be the answer. Either wait until the build is over and have it available as an artifact, or SSH the file outbound during the build.

Answer (score 0):

With the encouragement of @FelicianoTech, who is a CircleCI developer evangelist, I am posting the following advice.

You cannot SSH into a running CircleCI container unless you're using the SSH feature in the build UI, and that's really only for debugging. However, you could push a file out from inside the build at any time you like, if you have a service/server to push it to.